# Retrieving events from mailgun account

Tags: php, mailgun

I'm trying to keep track of all events happening on my Mailgun account. As per the documentation, something like this would work

```
$mailgun->events()->get('example.com');
```

My code is as below

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('API KEY');


$queryString = array(
    'begin' => 'Tue, 1 October 2019 09:00:00 -0000',
    'ascending' => 'yes',
    'limit' => 25,
    'pretty' => 'yes',
    'subject' => 'pulse'
);

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mg->events()->get('example.com', $queryString);
```

The result is a string, `Mailgun Magnificent API`.

I have also tried `$result = $mg->events()->get('example.com');` with similar results

I expceted a detailed JSON Object displaying my events or probably an unauthorized error message. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: How are you seeing that string, exactly? In your code you didn't show how you are using `$result` after you receive it. According to the code, the result should be an [EventResponse](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/master/src/Model/Event/EventResponse.php) object and you should be able to get the actual list of results by calling the "getItems()" method on that object.

Comment: It should have returned an Object. The initial error was `Uncaught Mailgun\Exception\HydrationException: Error (4) when trying to json_decode response`. I needed to see why the exact response.



I edited Mailgun `ModelHydrator` and I render `$result` to my screen  using `<div><?php printr($result);?></div>`. The returned response is `Mailgun Magnificent API` which of course cannot be represented as a JSON object.



Given that mailgun should return a JSON Object, I assumed there is something that I am missing

Comment: In retrospect I should have just checked the type of data I was dealing with... but again, it is a string, which results in the same problem. I wouldn't be able to move forward and use "getitems()" as you have suggested

Comment: _"I edited Mailgun ModelHydrator and I render $result to my screen using `<div><?php printr($result);?></div>.` "_ ...I don't quite understand, because `ModelHydrator->hydrate` doesn't have a `$result` variable. What did you change exactly? It would make more sense to do `print_r($body);` inside the `hydrate` function of that class to see the raw response body. Might also make sense to get hold of the headers (use `$response->getHeaders();` which will return an associative array (`string[][]`) of all response headers) in case there's an error status code or something to give a better clue

Comment: I kindly asked my boss to share with me the Mailgun credentials... It seems he had initially shared the wrong domain with me... :( Sorry for wasting your time. With regards your question `ModelHydrator` returns the variable `$object` which is a Json Decoded version of the variable `$body`. I edited it to actually return `$body` so that I could see the data. But as previously said... I had been provided with the wrong domain

Comment: Ok fine glad you resolved it. Annoying that mailgun doesn't actually give you a proper description of the error though

Comment: True... Thanks for taking the time